# Why do we convert accounts to AccountInfo?

Tags: anchor, account, accountinfo

I have this rust function

```
 pub fn purchase_ticket(ctx: Context<PurchaseTicket>, lottery_id: u32) -> Result<()> {
    let lottery = &mut ctx.accounts.lottery;
    let ticket = &mut ctx.accounts.ticket;
    let buyer = &ctx.accounts.buyer;
    
    invoke(
        &transfer(&buyer.key(), &lottery.key(), lottery.ticket_price),
        &[
            buyer.to_account_info(),
            lottery.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
    )?;
    ...
   }
```

I pass the accounts on front-end

```
const txHash = await program.methods
    .buyTicket(lotteryId)
    .accounts({
      lottery: lotteryAddress,
      ticket: ticketAddress,
      buyer: wallet.publicKey,
      systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
    })
    .rpc();
```

I did not understand this part:

```
      &[
            buyer.to_account_info(),
            lottery.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        ],
```

Why are we converting accounts to AccountInfo? What does Accountinfo help for here?

Answer (score 3):

In short, because account inputs are always of the type AccountInfo.

AccountInfo is the "base" account type - every account loaded into the program is deserialized from AccountInfo - in Anchor this happens behind the scenes (can see this by running anchor expand).

Your Context serves the accounts to your methods as the account types you've defined, but to preserve being able to pass them as AccountInfos, they can be converted to AccountInfo again using to_account_info().